# Post via ajax doesn't send data

Tags: c#, ajax, post, model-view-controller, null

I have the problem with post via ajax in my MVC application. I want to post a string, but in controller I get null. I found many similar problems, but still can't find a solution.
My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AddCompany(string data)
    {
        Company company = new Company { Name = data };
        await _context.Companies.AddAsync(company);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
```

And ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/api/companyApi/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            data: JSON.stringify("abc")
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function() {
            alert("The company added");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error! Please try again.');
        }

    });
```

Comment: your endpoint is called `AddCompany` where do you call it?

Comment: When I call /api/companyApi/addCompany I get 404 error. The controller is ApiController with routing [Route("api/[controller]")]. But when I call only /api/companyApi/ it reaches method AddCompany but with null in parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `/api/companyApi/` path. In order to make it work using **default** routing you need to make appropriate `Route` decorations.

Controller:

```
[Route("api")] //---> here is the change
public class YourControllerNameController
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("companyApi")] //---> here is the change
public async Task<ActionResult> AddCompany(string data)
{
    Company company = new Company { Name = data };
    await _context.Companies.AddAsync(company);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

Comment: It's my mistake that I didn't show the whole controller but `companyApi` is my name of controller. It is ApiController and it has routing `[Route("api/[controller]")]`. And `addCompany` is the name of action, but when I add it to url (`'/api/companyApi/addCompany'`) it returns 404. When I call only  `'/api/companyApi/'`  it reaches addCompany but with null parameters.

Comment: Your request can reach your `AddCompany` method when your are calling just `'/api/companyApi/'` because `AddCompany` is a single default POST endpoint in the controller. But I don't have explanation why `data` parameter is null, it should have value according to JS code your provided in original question